# Which option would we use with this sentence?

Tags: tense

```
I wanted to see Harry. How long ago ____
```

A) has he left ?
B)did he leave ?

Which option would fit ?

Comment: The second is correct. You can say "How long has he been gone?"

Comment: I'm not sure @Mick has it right here. Can you tell us what you think is the correct answer? Please use the [edit] link under your question to tell us which answer _you_ think is correct. That will make for a much better question!

Comment: @P.E.Dant The thing is that I don't know too but the answer seems to be true

Comment: @ysn_akst I was trying to motivate you to tell us what research you have done on your own. This makes for a better question, which leads to a more useful answer. Please read our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you to write a useful question. We hope you'll ask more of them.

Comment: @P.E.Dant OK, I got it. I remember we used ago with did but I wasn't sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the past simple, not the present perfect, with ago.

So the second sentence is Ok grammatically. How long ago did .....

However, you can use how long without ago in the present perfect.

A. How long ago did he leave?

B. Three hours ago.

A. How long has he left?

B. three hours.

Comment: Is there any reason we use ago with past simple or because it's just it, it's just the use of the langugae